# check if the timeout has passed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so i got this tempmute code for discord and it needs to check if the amount of time i told the bot to mute the user has passed
heres some code:

```
//tempmute
client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
    var member  = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]));
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'mute':    
setTimeout(function(){
                    member.roles.remove(role.id);
                    message.channel.send(`${member.user}` + ' has now been unmuted.')
                });
            break;
```

the problem is that it immediately unmutes
https://gyazo.com/9925922747ef3104ae8e146d47781b53 shown in this screenshot,
im very new to coding and discord js and dont know all the commands and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your timer into setTimeout

```
// if your input is in minutes you have to transform into millisecs 
var mute_time = parseInt(args[2]) * 60000;

setTimeout(() => {
     member.roles.remove(role.id);
     message.channel.send(`${member.user}` + ' has now been unmuted.')
}, mute_time);
```

Don't hesitate to accept as an answer if it help you :)

Comment: isn't args[1] that you need? If no, what the use of args[1] in you program ?

Comment: no, args[1] is for the user i want to mute.
the message is formatted as: (prefix the bot listens to)mute args[0] @user args [1] (time)[2]

Comment: Ok, can you put the snippet code that you posted by editing your original post plz?

Comment: i dont think i understand you, the code in the original post is the code in my visual studio code.

Comment: yes but you posted a snippet code in this post and you said you has another one bug?

Comment: yea, it had another bug for just 2 times but it works correct now
https://gyazo.com/f66b4b27fdec84356fd4808105b3b05f

Comment: it again immediately unmutes

Comment: ok your input (args[2] is in minutes or milliseconds?

Comment: so you should multiply by 60000 if your input is in minutes, i've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is because you omitted to pass a time to `setTimeout` as second parameter

Try

```
setTimeout(function(){
    member.roles.remove(role.id);
    message.channel.send(`${member.user}` + ' has now been unmuted.')
}, 3000); // Call the function after 3000ms
```

Comment: yes this works but i want the user of the command set the time, now it unmutes after 3000ms

Comment: Then you need to retrieve the timeout input in your code, probably by using something like `document.getElementById('my_explicit_id').value`. It depends on which element  you will display to collect that data. Don't forget to pass the timeout in ms

Comment: if im correct the time is stored in args[2] so i only need to set the setTimeout to args[2]

Comment: so what do you recommend me to do?
as i said im very new to js and dont really know much